# How can I resolve the ChartJS error message?

Tags: chart.js

I am upgrading from ChartJS v2 to v4 and receive the following stack-trace in the console:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: `target` argument of Reflect.getPrototypeOf must be an object, got undefined
    getPrototypeOf /js/chart.umd.js:13
    Xe http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    get http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    get http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    qe http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    get http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    update http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
    On http://localhost:8080/js/chart.umd.js:13
```

As far as I can tell, this is because an empty array is being sent into getPrototypeOf()

Comment: Please try to put yourself in the position of someone who would want to help you. How can anyone know what you have done wrong in the conversion to v4, from just that error stack that makes no reference whatever to your code? Even in the unlikely case that someone remembers to have had exactly that error and what caused it, you're asking for a guess, since such an error could have many causes in user code.  Please read the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) article and share a short runnable version of your code that exhibits that error.